# Karma AutoWatch not working when using Docker and Webpack

Tags: webpack, karma-runner, polling, file-watcher, karma-webpack

Using Karma's AutoWatch with Webpack, normally it re-runs all tests when a file is saved at the Webpack entrypoint. All I have to do is set `autoWatch: true` in the Karma config.

Once I put it in a Docker container, saving files does not cause Karma to re-run tests.

This is the same problem I had with Webpack and Nodemon. In both configs, I enabled polling and file watching worked in Docker.

How would I enable polling with Karma AutoWatch so it re-runs Webpack tests when file changes occur on the local filesystem while using Docker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `watchOptions` to Karma's `webpackMiddleware` so it re-run tests.

```
webpackMiddleware: {
    watchOptions: { poll: 100 }
}
```

Also ensure `restartOnFileChange` is not set to `true` because that will cause Karma to not find files when it reloads.